# Users Index Test Fail Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org

*Caveat: This is a novice question so pardon me.*

When I run my rails test on the rails sample app I am building, I get this error:

```
Failure:
UsersIndexTest#test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links [/home/ec2-user/environment/sample_app/test/integration/users_index_test.rb:16]:
Expected at least 1 element matching "div.pagination", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

and this one:

```
Failure:
UsersProfileTest#test_profile_display [/home/ec2-user/environment/sample_app/test/integration/users_profile_test.rb:17]:
Expected at least 1 element matching "div.pagination", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

Apparently, it has something to do with my show.html.erb file but I can't figure out what it is. Here are the file contents:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
      <%= @user.created_at %> <br>
      <%= @user.updated_at %> <br>
      <%= Time.now %>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea what the issue is.

Edit: Here are the tests:

1. user_profile_test.rb

....test "profile display" do

```
    get user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select 'title', full_title(@user.name)
    assert_select 'h1', text: @user.name
    assert_select 'h1>img.gravatar'
    assert_match @user.microposts.count.to_s, response.body
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    @user.microposts.paginate(page: 1).each do |micropost|
      assert_match micropost.content, response.body
    end
  end
```

end

2. users_index_test.rb

...test "index as admin including pagination and delete links" do

```
    log_in_as(@admin)
    get users_path
    assert_template 'users/index'
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
    first_page_of_users.each do |user|
      assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
      unless user == @admin
        assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete'
      end
    end
    assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
      delete user_path(@non_admin)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Is `div.pagination` a css selector?  Because if it is, there'll need to be a div with a class called "pagination" on it...

Comment: That looks like the output of an `assert_select`. Edit your post and add your tests!

Comment: When you run the website and hit a page, what does `<%= will_paginate @microposts %>` convert into? Is that what's supposed to be creating the `<div class="pagination">` that your test is missing?

Comment: normally the pagination div will be output by will_paginate, but will_paginate is only running if the user has microposts. Check that the user in the test has microposts, maybe? Will_paginate returns nil if there's nothing to paginate.

Comment: @Phlip, I have edited the question to include the tests.

Comment: @Shadow Radiance, the user in question has no microposts(yet). I, however, think the test should work regardless. No?

Comment: @DanRayson, I think it should not matter as rails recognises the css tags automatically

Comment: @ChidozieNnachor The CSS class doesn't exist in your markup.  That's why it's failing...

Comment: @DanRayson, I appreciate if you could be a bit more specific about what I need to do.

Comment: @ChidozieNnachor If you add a css class to any div in your markup, does it begin to work?  Like this `<div class="col-md-8 pagination">`.  If not, then I was actually wrong all along :(  I notice also that the `will_paginate` produces some extra markup - Have you tried what @Phlip said?

Comment: I added a css class <div.pagination> to the show.html.erb file. The first failing test passed. The second is still there.